# Access the API response and print it on button click in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, future

In login API it returns response, I want to get the response in button onclick and print it.

How can I do this?

```
   onTap: () async => {
           await propertyBloc.fetchAllCategory();

           <some code>

          },
```

Answer (score 0):

To do your task, you must need to do these things:

1. Call the API and get the response
2. Print on Tap

**1.** To get the response you must import the [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http), and then do this:

Make a method which gives out the response:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<http.Response> fetchData() async {
  final response =
      await http.get(your_url);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If server returns an OK response, parse the JSON.
    return json.decode(response.body);
  } else {
    // If that response was not OK, throw an error.
    throw Exception('Failed to load post');
  }
}
```

**2.**

```
//Call the function on tap of the button, which will return the data
onTap: (){this.fetchData();}
```

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Everything is fine , I can access the data through stream builder. But How can I access it in button onClick? And I have to store it in another variable or in local storage.

Comment: Access as in, in my representation, when you tap the button, you will be able to see the data. Do a print and log into the console.